# How do you use Jest to test img.onerror

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I've created a React component that loads an image and determines if the image loaded successfully or not.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { LOADING, SUCCESS, ERROR } from '../helpers';

class Image extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    onError: PropTypes.func,
    onLoad: PropTypes.func,
    src: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    onError: null,
    onLoad: null,
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { imageStatus: LOADING };
    this.initImage();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.image.onload = this.handleImageLoad;
    this.image.onerror = this.handleImageError;
    this.image.src = this.props.src;
  }

  initImage() {
    this.image = document.createElement('img');
    this.handleImageLoad = this.handleImageLoad.bind(this);
    this.handleImageError = this.handleImageError.bind(this);
  }

  handleImageLoad(ev) {
    this.setState({ imageStatus: SUCCESS });
    if (this.props.onLoad) this.props.onLoad(ev);
  }

  handleImageError(ev) {
    this.setState({ imageStatus: ERROR });
    if (this.props.onError) this.props.onError(ev);
  }

  render() {
    switch (this.state.imageStatus) {
      case LOADING:
        return this.renderLoading();
      case SUCCESS:
        return this.renderSuccess();
      case ERROR:
        return this.renderError();
      default:
        throw new Error('unknown value for this.state.imageStatus');
    }
  }
}

export default Image;
```

I'm trying to create a test using Jest + Enzyme to test when an image fails to load.

```
  it('should call any passed in onError after an image load error', () => {
    const onError = jest.fn();
    mount(<Image {...props} src="crap.junk"} onError={onError} />);
    expect(onError).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

No matter what I do, Jest always finds a way to successfully render the image.  Even setting src to false still renders an image somehow.  Does anyone know how in the heck you can force jest to fail an image load?

Comment: I realized that I was testing something beyond the scope of my code. I was trying to test a browser's ability to handle an image load failure. I have to trust that the HTMLImageElement API in the browser can handle image failures correctly.  If it doesn't, then the browser itself has issues.  Chances of a browser like Chrome allowing a bug like that to make it into their production code: nill. So, I just decided to use wrapper.instance() and then call instance.image.onerror() directly.  I'm trying to test my code, not the browser.

Answer (score 21):

If you're using [@testing-library/react](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/), you can trigger the error on the `img` with `fireEvent.error`:

```js
const onError = jest.fn();
render(<Image alt="test" src="crap.junk"} onError={onError} />);
fireEvent.error(screen.getByAltText("test"));
expect(onError).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: fireEvent doesn't have an `error` key!!!

Comment: This worked for my case. I wanted to see if the correct React component rendered after an image load error occurred.

Answer (score 20):

Since behind the scenes, `document.createElement('img')` is equivalent to `new Image()`, we can mock part of the jsdom (used by Jest) implementation of `Image` to achieve what you're going for.

(For simplicity's sake, I've renamed your component to `ImageComponent`)

```
describe('Callbacks', () => {
  const LOAD_FAILURE_SRC = 'LOAD_FAILURE_SRC';
  const LOAD_SUCCESS_SRC = 'LOAD_SUCCESS_SRC';

  beforeAll(() => {
    // Mocking Image.prototype.src to call the onload or onerror
    // callbacks depending on the src passed to it
    Object.defineProperty(global.Image.prototype, 'src', {
      // Define the property setter
      set(src) {
        if (src === LOAD_FAILURE_SRC) {
          // Call with setTimeout to simulate async loading
          setTimeout(() => this.onerror(new Error('mocked error')));
        } else if (src === LOAD_SUCCESS_SRC) {
          setTimeout(() => this.onload());
        }
      },
    });
  });

  it('Calls onError when passed bad src', done => {
    const onError = ev => {
      expect(ev).toBeInstanceOf(Error);

      // Indicate to Jest that the test has finished
      done();
    };

    mount(<ImageComponent onError={onError} src={LOAD_FAILURE_SRC} />);
  });
});
```

The reason `onerror`/`onload` is never called as it would be in a browser is explained in this [jsdom issue](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1816#issuecomment-310106280). An alternate fix that would affect all your tests is offered up in the same [issue thread](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1816#issuecomment-355188615).

Comment: This works for me. However, it doesn't look like there's a way to unset `Object.defineProperty` at the end of the test suite, to restore `Image.prototype.src` back to the way it was.

Comment: If you look at the edit history for this answer, you'll see that I used to have such cleanup logic in there, but I removed it because I confirmed that the modified prototype only existed within a certain scope (either the `describe` block, or the file scope, I don't recall), and was restored afterwards. If you want the older restore-included code, get it from the answer history.

Comment: @Chris It persists within the same test suite (i.e. file). The issue arises if you have multiple tests in the same file that rely on Image.src to work as expected. Every test should clean up after itself as to not affect other tests IMHO.

Comment: Depending on what you want to test it might make sense to return the given `src` as well: ```Object.defineProperty(global.Image.prototype, 'src', { set(src) { this._src = src; setTimeout(() => this.onload && this.onload()) }, get() { return this._src; }```

Answer (score 0):

You could mock `document.createElement`:

```
 it('should call any passed in onError after an image load error', () => {
    const img = {}
    global.document.createElement = (type) => type === 'img' ? img : null
    const onError = jest.fn();
    mount(<Image {...props} src="crap.junk"} onError={onError} />);
    img.onload()
    expect(onError).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: I think you are onto something, but there are issues with mocking document.createElement.  My Image function also creates spans and divs depending on the arguments, so returning null causes the test to crash.  Right now I'm testing to see if I can add any attribute at all.  It's not working. This is as far as I've gotten:  https://gist.github.com/mrbinky3000/567b532928f456ee74e55ebe959c66ec

Comment: I gave up.  I just decided to use wrapper.instance() and then call instance.image.onerror() directly.  It occurred to me that I was over-testing.  I have to trust that HTMLImageElement will fire onerror when there is an image error. If not, then there's a monumental error with the source code of the web browser.  Odds of that: nil.  So I just manually fired the error to simulate an error.  Case closed.  Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

I use jest + Enzyme. I just invoke the onError method manually, like this:

```
function Avatar (props) {
    const handleError = (e) => {
        e.target.src = getDefaultSrc()
    }

    const getDefaultSrc = () => {
        return `/default.png`
    }

    const { user: { avatar } } = props
    return <img className='avatar' src={avatar} onError={handleError} />
}

// avatar.test.js
it('should show default image', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Avatar {...props} />)
    const handleError = wrapper.find('.avatar').prop('onError')
    expect(typeof handleError).toBe('function')
    const fakeE = {
        target: {
            src: ''
        }
    }
    
    handleError(fakeE)
    expect(fakeE.target.src).toBe('/default.png')
})
```