# jest + enzyme: how to handle async image.onload inside 3d party library

Tags: image, reactjs, onload, enzyme, jestjs

I'm writing unit tests using Jest and Enzyme for my component, which uses 3rd party library (CropperJs), where there is event listener set on image upload. There is 'new Image' object created inside library with the source that I pass in base64 format. When that image is uploaded inside 3rd party component, the library should render some DOM nodes. I need access to those nodes in my tests. But as image.onload is asynchronous, my test pass earlier then library renders needed nodes.

Does someone know how can I handle this async action or how can I put spy to image (inside 3rd party library) loading and needed nodes exist in the DOM?
I'm using 'jsdom' to mock document

Comment: I think the technique used in my answer here will also work in your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49204336/1601953