# How to use Jest to test if image has loaded

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have this component that loads an image and then only displays content after the image is loaded (checks for image loading state).  How do a write a jest test to test that it is working properly and that the content only displays after the image has loaded and not before?

```
import HeaderImage from '../images/headerimage.svg';

const ImageStyled = styled.img`
  margin-left: -0.1rem;
`;


export default class ImageDisplay extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { imageStatus: 'loading' };
  }


  handleImageLoaded() {
    this.setState({ imageStatus: 'loaded' });
  }

  renderContent = () => (
     if (this.state.imageStatus === 'loading') {
    return null;
     }  
   else {
      <div>
      Some Sample Content
      </div>   
   }

  render() {
    return (     
       <div>
          <ImageStyled
            src={HeaderImage}
            onLoad={() => {
              this.handleImageLoaded();
            }}
          />
          {this.renderContent()}
        </div>

   );
  }
}
```

`

Comment: maybe worth referencing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44462665/how-do-you-use-jest-to-test-img-onerror trying to mock the browser's/jsdom's image load event might be more trouble than it's worth