# Simulate img.onError using jest/enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I Have an image in a component that triggers an onerror func when the img1 wont load, my question is how can i test this onError using jest/enzyme?

```
       <img
           alt={institute}
           src={img1}
           onError={e => {
                      e.target.onError = null
                      e.target.src = defaultImg
                         }}
          className={img1}
      />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49204336/340760